# Custom Object to JSON with SWIFT 2 and Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, object, request, swift2

I have have a custom class like this:

```
public class myObject
{
    var isActive : Bool
    var Name : String

    init(isActive : Bool, name : String)
    {
        self.isActive = isActive
        self.Name = name
    }
}
```

I save "n" objects from type `myObject` in a Array: `let myArray = [myObject]`

How can I serialize `myArray`?

```
let json = JSON(myArray)
```

to give me a JSON object, but i need a String to send this with the `Alamofire.manager.request(.PUT,URL,**parameters**....)`.

How can I do this?

Thx, 
Nero

Comment: Did you try json.rawString()?

Comment: Yes, I tried this but json.rawString() ist empty. Only rawArray has my objects.

Comment: what are you trying to send?